# zend form handling of NULL from DB to form and back to DB

Tags: null, sql-update, http-post, zend-form, zero

I have a DB table with various columns of various types including a few decimal typed columns which may or may not be significant. I read a record from the database and through error_log I output the resulting associative array using serialize($dbArray) and I can clearly see that the columns have an 'N' signifying that they contain a NULL value. This same array is used in the $form->populate($dbArray) to "populate" the form. Upon submission, I use error_log again with the serialize($dbArray) and the columns in question now have 'S(1):0' as the value portion of the serialize output.

This is an issue for me because I have a validator for greaterThan 0 which fails when I expect it to pass when I do not eter any value into that particular element. The elements are not required elements and should only run the validator when something is entered and because NULL is not returned it gets run. Somewhere the NULL value is converted to 0 which is subsequently turned to 0.00 in the DB.

Any idea what I need to do to get the Form to return NULL when nothing is entered into the element. I have the element defined as type 'text' which I use for most elements of this nature. There are varchars from the same DB record that are returned as NULL, and I think I recall a date column that is also keeping the NULL value. These are also 'text' elements in the Form.

I will be back at it tomorrow and will be debugging some more, but any ideas about what might cause this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that this can be handled with the use of filters (Zend_Filter) and I am in the process of doing so now. I will return and specify the details when I have it working, and if I fail then I guess that might be another question.

Okay, so the filter worked. Basically, where I defined my element I simply had to add an

`->addFilter('Null')`

which causes the getValue or getValues to return a NULL rather than an empty string or 0 and that is just what I needed. There are a number of variable/column types that this filter will convert to a NULL and it says that it works basically the way the php empty() function does and when empty returns true then this filter will return a NULL otherwise it returns the contents as they are.

I hope this helps someone avoid the research time I had to put in.